# Remove Link Formatting From Google Mail Signature?

Tags: email, web-applications, gmail, signature

I have a signature within my Google Mail Signature with link in it. When I try to change the color/text it formats my links as links. I understand that, links, when called out may appear as links instead of just text. But I would like to just have them as texts so I may format the colors and weight.

Comment: This would be better suited on [Webapps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a permanent solution to this and I've been searching for a while.  The only **temporary** workaround I've found is removing/disabling the hyperlink tag from my signature and this will keep the **non hyperlink** signature as long as I **don't logout** of Gmail.\

Answer (score 19):

Gmail converts link text automatically to links so you might as well keep them as links. You can change the colour with the wysiwyg editor, but to remove the underline you need to edit the raw HTML. You can do that by right clicking and "inspect element" in chrome (or use firebug or similar) and add a `style="text-decoration:none"` to the `<a>` tag.

Obviously if you change it in the email it will only work once. To change it permanently go to your settings > signature; edit the html using the element inspector and save.

Comment: Firebug and/or element inspection is for development purposes only, changing it won't affect server-side, it only affects client-side. This means it doesn't fix anything technically.

Comment: thanks for the laugh.. 
Writing an email **is** _client-side_, it is then submitted to the server and sent.

Comment: I'm not talking about the mail. What you change in a development inspector only affects the way YOU view things - your browser. You can go to facebook and change their logo to google+, you're only doing it client-side. Server never receives anything so therefore in the gmail signature you can do all you want, as soon as you refresh it's all gone because you're only changing the way YOU view things.

Comment: If you change the comment you are writing in facebook with the element inspector it changes what is submitted to the server. The same is true of emails. Obviously changing the gmail logo isnt going to persist. I can see why you are confused though - I've made my answer more specific.

Comment: :D just think of it like wordpress.. when you edit a post, whether you change the text with a keyboard or change the html with the inspector, it gets saved when you submit it to the server. 
(you can upvote if it worked)

Comment: This does not actually work. I am saving my signature with text decoration none, and it looks fine for a couple of sends, but then when I switch to another laptop or after a few days, I see the underline has returned and my links are now underlined again.

Comment: Worked for me. If it doesn't work right away, try clearing your browser cache and doing a hard refresh.

Comment: @coldpumpkin I agreed with you, but TimoSolo's solution worked on my second try.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work for me - a bit dangerous but works in my tests.

```
<a style="color: #fff;text-decoration: none;" href="mailto:email@domain.com" target="_blank"><span style="color:#2b2b2b;">email@domain.com</span></a>
```

When I copy the resulting html from my browser and paste in the Gmail Signature box, and then Compose a new email in Gmail - the lines do not appear and the text is colored correctly. :)

Answer (score 3):

Super old thread, but this Zendesk article worked for me:

1. Open your signature again in a different browser (such as Firefox)
2. Select the preview using the button, and copy
3. Go to Gmail settings, and the signature box
4. Paste in your signature
5. Scroll down and press 'Save'
6. Reload Gmail in Chrome
7. Send a test email, which should have the correctly formatting for links now

[Links in my email signature are underlined sending from Gmail](https://signaturehelp.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003474689-Links-in-my-email-signature-are-underlined-sending-from-Gmail)

Comment: OOOOOH yeeees! It worked. I just used Safari and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all the solutions in this thread, but none of them work. Gmail will strip any text-decoration: none you may added to your signatures, no matter what shape or form, after refreshing the page/logging in again.

A curious thing I noticed, is that a signature that I created years ago actually does have links that don't get underlined. I tried to copy this signature into my new account, but the same problem occurred. I suspect that this is something Google didn't do until a few years back, and as such any signatures created before that time remain unaffected, but new ones get force fed an underline.

Really obnoxious how Google forces this stuff down our throats, but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be anything that can be done about it at this stage.

Comment: hmm.. that's annoying. Perhaps try a signature plugin like https://www.wisestamp.com/ which uses a chrome extension to inject the signature into the email bypassing the gmail signature.

Comment: One shouldn't have to pay to be able to include a simple signature in one's email without underlined links...

Answer (score 1):

I have found a permanent and very simple solution for removing underline from the links in Google Mail Signature. 
Just you need to open your signature in HTML editor and add the following style:

```
<style>a,a[href],a:hover{text-decoration:none !important;}</style>
```

I hope you are satisfied with my answer. If still facing any issues, must reply.

Thanks! :)

Comment: If you can add a class on your HTML signature (e.g. `.my-signature`), then you can prefix the styles so not ALL the links in your have no underline—only the ones in your signature: `.my-signature a,.my-signature a[href], .my-signature a:hover{text-decoration:none !important;}`

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything here, but the underline only went away when I pasted the signature in Firefox instead of Chrome per this thread, https://litmus.com/community/discussions/6993-remove-underline-from-links-on-emails-sent-from-gmail-to-outlook

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have ever been able to remove the hyperlink is to insert a space somewhere in the link and change the font size of the space to something smaller. This is likely a terrible solution, but it is good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Fix, you're on the right track. I followed your instructions but obviously didn't want the gap created so I then deleted the space. After saving, logging in and out again some of the link was fixed.. Just the .co.uk at the end showed as a link so I used the same technique (between the ".co" and the ".uk") and it now works a treat! :)

Answer (score 0):

My work-arounds:

1. For a phone number, use "~" instead of "-" (eg. 1~800~444~4444)
2. You can upload a picture to your signature, so you can create your signature in Paint and save it as a jpeg or png file.  For some reason, my picture was not looking very crisp, so I used the tilde sign in the phone number instead.

Answer (score 0):

I battled with this for ages, but eventually managed to solve it with a cheap hack:

Break your email up into two bits of text next to each other, so that it's not recognisable as an address.

```
<font>lozmis@</font><font>gmail.</font><font>com</font>
```

It probably wasn't necessary to break it up three times but I was done with it so I went with the sure thing.